# Class objects and Multi threading in python

Tags: python, multithreading, class

I am using multithreading for the first time and here is the problem in which I am stuck.

I have a class `Workstation` and want to use a separate thread for each instance of the class. Each instance has to draw some cell phone models defined in the global list, but multithreading does not work for all instances, it works well only for one object and the rest seem to hang.

Here is code for my class and in the main file I am using another thread(code for that also attached below the class code) that runs a while loop forever and inside that loop, I am calling "drawing_thread"
function for each object of workstation-class.

why threading only works for the first object, not for others

```
import requests, time, db_quries, threading
from datetime import datetime
import helper_functions as HF

LocIP = '192.168.100.100'
# Local port for server
LocPort = 4321

class Workstation:
    def __init__(self,FCell):
        """
        constructor for class workstation
        :param FCell:
        """
        self.FCell = FCell # cell number

        #initial values of component's flag
        self.frame_done = True
        self.screen_done = False
        self.kpad_done = False

        #flags for order compeltion
        self.make = 1
        self.complete = 0
        self.thread_flag=True

    #mutators for object variables

    def make_setter(self):
        self.make = self.make+1
        #print('FL1: Make ',self.make)

    def set_m(self,m):
        self.make=m

    def complete_setter(self,complete):
            self.complete =complete
            #print('FL1: complete ',self.complete)

    def set_frame(self, value):
        self.frame_done = value

    def set_screen(self, value):
        self.screen_done = value

    def set_kpad(self, value):
        self.kpad_done = value

    def set_thread_flag(self,value):
        self.thread_flag = value

    def drawing_thread(self,param):
            self.thread_flag = False
            drawing = threading.Thread(target=HF.production, args=param)
            drawing.start()
```

function that called by thread in main file

```
def process_thread():
    while True:
        #print(len(OrderList))
        if WS_obj_list[0].thread_flag and WS_obj_list[0].get_zone_status('Z1') != '-1':
            WS_obj_list[0].drawing_thread((WS_obj_list[0], OrderList))

        if WS_obj_list[1].thread_flag and WS_obj_list[1].get_zone_status('Z1') != '-1':#
            WS_obj_list[1].drawing_thread((WS_obj_list[1], OrderList))

        if WS_obj_list[2].thread_flag and WS_obj_list[2].get_zone_status('Z1') != '-1':
            WS_obj_list[2].drawing_thread((WS_obj_list[2], OrderList))

        time.sleep(1)
```